Installing JavaFX for M2 Mac (Eclipse)
I am attempting to install JavaFX on my Mac in Eclipse, but I keep running into a "Quantum Renderer" error.
I have two successful JavaFX setups on my Windows machine, and the VM arguments and build paths are identical to my setup. I am aware that if you download the wrong architecture SDK, it will give that error. I have downloaded the aarch64 architecture, which is the architecture for my M2 MacBook. I have no clue where I'm going wrong. I'm posting a few things below to help out.
My build path:

My VM arguments:
--module-path /Users/sohammukherjee/Downloads/javafx-sdk-22.0.1/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls

The error:
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1085)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1085)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics@22.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    ... 5 more

Please help me out.

You might also want to try moving JavaFX to the modulepath as it sometimes works better with modules. Also, why do you have a JavaFX SDK entry as well as the JARs on their own?

Okay, we're getting somewhere. After I moved the JavaFX SDK to the Module Path, that disgusting error went away, and now I have the error "Module javafx.controls not found".
I have to add the external jars separately because otherwise the whole program errors out and doesn't recognize what JavaFX is.

As jewelsea mentions, you can alternatively choose to use a JDK/JRE that comes bundled with the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries. At least two vendors supply them: Azul Systems and BellSoft.

It is unclear why you question tells about "My VM arguments". If you entered this somewhere as text, you doing something wrong. Please follow the JavaFX documentation Getting Started with JavaFX - JavaFX and Eclipse instead.

@howlger the referenced document section "JavaFX and Eclipse: Non-modular from the IDE. Section Add VM Arguments. Linux/Mac" requests to enter VM arguments as text --module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-22.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml in the IDE under Run -> Run Configurations...  -> Java Application, so I guess the asker is already following that guide or something like it, but has some kind of mistake or misconfiguration in their following of the guide and setup.

No toolkit found means some native components were unable to load.
Configuring your IDE
Looking at your screenshot, the path to your javafx.graphics.jar is wrong, it points to the lit directory, not the lib directory. (I don't know if that is your only issue).
Another thing to check (you can screenshot it in your question if you like) is what the run configuration looks like (the linked screenshot is from the openjfx doc for non-modular JavaFX applications from the Eclipse IDE).

After I moved the JavaFX SDK to the Module Path, . . . now I have the error "Module javafx.controls not found".

If the javafx modules aren't found then your module path is wrong.
Alternative: Using Maven or Gradle, integrated with your IDE
If you continue to have issues, there are other ways to develop JavaFX, as documented in the openjfx.io getting started instructions.
You can use Eclipse integration with a modular maven application. Maven or Gradle builds download JavaFX dependencies from Maven Central. Unlike the JavaFX code in the SDK, those are packaged to include, inside the JavaFX jars, all of the required native code for your target architecture (dynamically extracting the native components to a local cache on runtime).
In the long run, IMO, it is better to use a build tool like Maven or Gradle, which all major IDEs will integrate with, rather than manually configuring an IDE environment.
Alternative: Use a JDK/JRE that includes JavaFX
You can use a JDK for your environment (M series Mac) that already includes JavaFX - that way you don't need to configure the module path, add modules to the module graph, or use the JavaFX SDK at all.
As noted in comments by Basil, you can:

use a JDK/JRE that comes bundled with the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries. At least two vendors supply them: Azul Systems and BellSoft.

Both vendors also provide JDKs and JREs that don't include JavaFX. If you follow this approach, ensure that you choose the right JDK/JRE version that both includes JavaFX and is built for your architecture (in your case Mac M series aarch64 processors), using only recent LTS or non-LTS builds as best match your requirements.
Background Info on Native Libraries in JavaFX
The usual cause for "runtime components are missing" or "No toolkit found" style errors is that some required native libraries needed by JavaFX or their system dependencies did not load correctly because they could not be found, or were the wrong version that did not match your Java source.
On Windows, native libraries are DLLs. On OS X, native libraries are dylib files.
JavaFX will find native libraries in this way:

looking for the native libraries in a directory adjacent to the JavaFX jar files being loaded (on the module path or classpath).
looking for the native libraries on the Java load library path.
extracting the native libraries from jar versions that include them, copying them to a local cache and loading them from there.

JavaFX jars in maven central do include native libraries.
JavaFX jars in the JavaFX SDK do not include native libraries.


Using the native libraries included in modules that are packaged in a jlinked runtime image (e.g. jlinked jmod files that form an image).

Unless you are developing the JavaFX framework itself, you only need to use the native libraries at runtime, not at compile-time, so errors in finding and using the native libraries are runtime errors, not compile-time errors.
Usually, you don't need to worry about how JavaFX finds native libraries.  There is no specific configuration you need to do to allow the libraries to be found.  However, you should ensure at least one of the following is occurring:

correctly specifying the module path for your application and ensuring that either of the following are on that path:

The JavaFX modules from Maven Central on the module path.
OR the JavaFX libraries from the JavaFX SDK including the associated native files.



OR

using a jlinked runtime image that already includes the JavaFX modules.

